# Swift - Como parar uma animação?

Tags: swift, mobile

Em minha Viewcontroler inicial possuo um slide que fica carregando da internet e alternado na tela imagens num tempo estipulado por mim.

Como eu posso parar a animação? Queria fazer isso antes de ir para outra ViewController

## Animação:

```
func animate(images: [String], index: Int = 0) {
    print(index)
    UIView.transitionWithView(imageView, duration: 10, options: .TransitionCrossDissolve, animations: {
        if let checkedUrl = NSURL(string: self.vetString[index]) {
            self.downloadImage(checkedUrl)
        }
        }, completion: { value in
            let idx = index == images.count-1 ? 0 : index+1
            self.animate(self.vetString, index: idx)
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Descobri uma forma. Fiz assim:

```
@IBAction func paraAnimacao(sender: AnyObject) {
    var layer = imageView.layer.presentationLayer() as! CALayer
    var frame = layer.frame
    print(frame)
    imageView.layer.removeAllAnimations()
    imageView.frame = frame
}
```